# Extrair arquivo .ZIP com acento no nome

Tags: c#, .net, codificação-de-caracteres, arquivo-zip

Estou usando a lib `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` para descompactar arquivos **.zip** e me deparei com um grande problema ao tentar extrair arquivos que tenham acentos no nome.

Se eu tentar extrair com a codificação **UTF-8**:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(caminhoArquivoZip, "E:\\localParaExtrair", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Os arquivos que tem nome com acento ficam com o carácter � no lugar do letra acentuada.

Se eu passar outro `Encoding` (`Unicode`, por exemplo), é lançada uma *exception*:

> Não há suporte à codificação de nome de entrada especificada.

Se tentar com `Encoding.Default` outro carácter estranho fica no lugar da letra acentuada.

Isso é um problema da biblioteca? Tem alguma forma de conseguir extrair esses arquivos corretamente?

Eu tenho plena consciência de que não se deve escrever nome de arquivos com acentos, mas não sou eu quem cria os arquivos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com esse Enconding funciona:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(caminhoArquivoZip, "E:\\localParaExtrair", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850));
```

> O `GetEncoding` inicializa uma nova instância da classe `Encoding` correspondente à **página de código** especificada.

(Fonte: [documentação do .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx))

A página de código **850** representa a codificação **ibm850** - *Europeu oriental (DOS)*

Comment: Caraca, muito bom. Tu podes complementar a resposta explicando o porquê do parâmetro **850** no `.GetEncoding()`?

Comment: Valeu pela complementação @JéfersonBueno

Comment: comigo não funcionou, e apareceu o erro: System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 850

Comment: comigo não funcionou, e apareceu o erro: System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 850

Answer (score 0):

O nome do arquivo e/ou nome da pasta não podem conter algums caractéres especiais, como acentuação. Assim como pastas não podem ter ?/%$ ......

Até mesmo se tentar diretamente no windows explorer ele te devolverá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pastas podem sim ter carácteres acentuados. http://imgur.com/TH9Xf8m

Comment: Pastas podem sim, mas o zippamento de arquivos em pastas com acentos, não.

Comment: Essa resposta está incorreta. Acentuação pode ser usada normalmente em pastas e arquivos dentro de um .zip, sem problemas. A pergunta não se refere em nenhum momento a caracteres "proibidos" pelo OS.

Comment: [Window Title]
Compressed (zipped) Folders Error

[Content]
'C:\Users\henrique.brisola\Downloads\[Untitled].split\PROFARMA DISTRIBUIDORA DE PRODUTOS FARMACÊUTICOS S.A' cannot be compressed because it includes characters that cannot be used in a compressed folder, such as Ê. You should rename this file or directory.

[OK]